# Mvc4 to Mvc5, do they work side by side

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have installed MVC4. If I install MVC5 now, keeping the MVC4 instalation, will I still be able to run my MVC4 projects?

Comment: yep. your existing projects keeps the same NuGet packages so unless you update those in your project all stays the same...at least from my experience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5

" It installs side-by-side with ASP.NET MVC 4"